# How I can adding ListView Header to my app?

Tags: android

Could you let me know how I can add a header to my app?

Could anyone guide me on how to do that the easy way?

This is code for this Website:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 
<!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 
<!-- Single ListItem -->
 
<!-- Product Name -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
    // List view
    private ListView lv;
     
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
     
     
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         
        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
         
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
         
        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
         
        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }
             
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 
            }
             
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is issue with this?

Comment: It seems you already have a header (an EditText)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein: I think the op wants the header should scroll while `ListView` is scrolled.

Comment: So, IMO, that's not a **real** header. Real header and footers are **permanent**. If they scroll, then they are nothing but items...

Comment: Yeah I agree, header and footers are nothing but a fixed view which will scroll along with the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the `ListView` use method `addHeaderView(View v)`

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
lV.addHeaderView(header)
```

Where `R.layout.header` is a resource containing the layout of your header.

Please in the future google or the search function on stackoverflow, simple questions like these are already answered or very easy to find on the web. For learning how to use the `ListView` i suggest you take [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This can be acheive by making a separate layout for your header, after that inflate that layout and perform addHeaderView(inflated view) to your list.. after doing this set listview adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like below,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv , false); //header is your layout in which you can add what ever view you want.
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

But add it before setting the adapter of the `ListView`otherwise header won't show up.

Reference
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)